# Split a data frame into smaller sub data frames and process a command one by one in R

Tags: r, loops, split

I am working on a data set with over 2 millions of records. I want to run a function deyo() on the entire data set but the process took more than 12 hours and still not finished. I think i might hit the ram limit. How I can break the data set and process smaller chunks each time and get the out put in the same file?

Deyo is a function from comorbidities package and it takes the data frame as an arguement. deyo(df). The output is one vector and two dataframes, and I only need to use the vector.
so for the whole dataset I will do score<-deyo(df)$score.

Comment: It will need a little bit more detail on how data looks like and what your function returns. But generally, subset dataset by some criteria, here it seems no. of rows is enough, lets say df[1:10000,] etc and make list of datasets, and apply your function to that list.

Comment: How are you running the function on the entire data set?  Row by row in a loop?  Or does the function take the data frame as an argument?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for some kind of parallel processing...but I guess that depends on what `deyo` is/does.

Comment: The function take the entire data frame as an argument. So i will do deyo(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2<-split(df, rep(1:200, each=1000))
sapply(df2,deyo)
```

Comment: deyo(df) generates a vector and two data frames. what I need is the vector. I normally do score<-deyo(df)$score. In this case how i can get the vector for each subset of data in one file?

Comment: `lapply(lapply(df2,deyo),"[[","index of score from deyo output")`

Comment: I was able to get it by
df2<-split(df, rep(1:200, each=1000))
score<-sapply(df2,deyo)[1,]
thanks

Comment: make sure those rep thing is working for you, here it works for 200000, so make sure to change your parameters to include all your data

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this problem quite often when scoring large data sets. I use this function to divide the data frame into a list of smaller data frames:

```
createFrameList <- function(myData, frames){
# Creates a list of equally sized data frames of equal size
  rownames(myData) <- seq(1:dim(myData)[1])
  return(split(myData, (as.numeric(rownames(myData)) - 1) %/% ceiling(nrow(myData) / frames)))
  }
```

And then I can run either `lapply` or `mclapply` from the `parallel` package (if I'm on a UNIX/Linux box) to run my function each data frame. You'll get a list back of whatever your function returns when applied to a data frame. If your function returns another frame, you can use `rbind.fill` from the `plyr` package to assemble your list back into a singe data frame.

Comment: deyo(df) out puts one vector and two data frames, I used your method and created list df2, then
df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(df2,deyo)) was able to generate the outputs for each subframe.  But if I only want the vector in each output, what I can do?

Comment: I'd have to see the function to tell you for sure, but if the function returns a vector and two data frames, when you call lapply(deyo) on a list of data frames then the output list should be a list of vectors and data frames, you could probably just pull the vectors using normal list slicing via index.